# Three.js - Cylinder inner texture

Tags: javascript, jquery, three.js

I'm completely new to Three.js and use it for now only for a side feature on a website.

I'm trying to render a paper cup (or something that reminds a paper cup) with different textures on the outer side and inner side.

So far I've managed to do something like that. rotate left <--> right using keyboard arrows.

[Simple Demo](http://37.59.53.90:8080/1.html)

How can I add a different texture for the inner side of the cup (where the red arrow points).
without a texture, the rotation looks a bit strange.
and I'll be happy to hear any suggestion to how to make it better in terms of visual

Thank you

[image]

Comment: Create another cylinder, put it inside the outer one and use `side: THREE.BackSide` for its material.

Comment: Amazing!! clever idea. can u elaborate on side: Three.Backside.. where do I set it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a concept of how you can do it:

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 3, 5);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});
renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff);
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

var geometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(2, 1.5, 4, 32, 1, true);
var materialOuter = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load("https://threejs.org/examples/textures/758px-Canestra_di_frutta_(Caravaggio).jpg")
});
var materialInner = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load("https://threejs.org/examples/textures/UV_Grid_Sm.jpg"),
  side: THREE.BackSide
});

var meshOuter = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, materialOuter);
var meshInner = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, materialInner);
meshOuter.add(meshInner);
scene.add(meshOuter);

render();

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/93/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

Comment: AMAZING!!! how to you change the background to white?? I'm adding lights

Comment: @Kulpemovitz I've updated the answer. Used renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff).

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to @prisoner849's answer, you can use a custom shader material and check whether the rendered fragment is backfacing and give it its own color (texture...)

```
vec3 frontMaterial = vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0); //red
vec3 backMaterial = vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);  //green

//make every fragment green
gl_FragColor = vec4( frontMaterial, 1.0 );
//make fragments green when on the inner side of the object model
if (!gl_FrontFacing) gl_FragColor = vec4(backMaterial, 1.0);
```

[Here's a live example](https://shaderfrog.com/app/view/2050)